# linq syntax to match dynamic sql IN statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity

Does anyone know how to do this with a string representation of IDs, to look for I tried the above and none worked for my style formatting. I have a string that is "1,2,3,4,5" which represents the IDs I am looking for... but the string does not get recognized as being seperate IDs for the IN statement usual to SQL syntax...

```
string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
var recs = from tb1 in c2d where new[]{IDs}.Contains(tb1.RID) select tb1;
```

I know my string works in sql syntax that is ad hoc as follows...

```
string sSql = "select * from table where IDs in ("+ IDs + ")"; 
exec sql;
```

I am just looking for some equivalent to keeping my synatx quick and dirty

Answer (score 4):

You need to put that string data in an `int` array and use a `Contains()` query:

```
int[] ids = new [] {1,2,3,4,5};
var recs = from tb1 in c2d where ids.Contains(tb1.RID) select tb1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to use a string you have to split it into an array and cast the string value into an `int` before you can use it.

```
string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
var recs = from tb1 in c2d 
           where IDs.Split(',')
                 .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                 .Contains(tb1.RID) 
           select tb1;
```

If you could use an int array directly instead of a string that would be preferably

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into its components, and you can then use `Contains`:

```
var validIds = IDs.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var recs = c2d.Where(tb1 => validIds.Contains(tb1.RID));
```

(I'm assuming `RID` is an `int` property...)

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, define your IDs as a HashSet for O(1) lookup:

```
string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(IDs.Split(','));
var recs = from tb1 in c2d where set.Contains(tb1.RID) select tb1;
```

Or if `RID` is an `int`:

```
string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(IDs.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
var recs = from tb1 in c2d where set.Contains(tb1.RID) select tb1;
```